# Automating Database Counts for All SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need database counts for every SQL server instance (PROD/Non PROD) in an environment.

If I logged into each and every SQL Server then it is very tedious task for me, so I need to automate it.

Is there any t-sql or powershell script from which I can get consolidated report for database counts for all servers at one place.

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not provide you with what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-2017) module documentation, specifically the [Get-SqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/Get-SqlDatabase?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet. You can import your server names from a file or define them in an array and then iterate through them.

```
#get your credential
$credentials = get-credential
#read server names from a file
$servers = get-content "C:\Some\Path\servers.txt"
#use calculated properties
$servers | select-object `
    @{Name='ServerName';Expression={$_}},
    @{Name='DatabaseCount';Expression={
        #force to array to ensure .count exists
        @(Get-SqlInstance -MachineName $_ -Credential $credential | Get-SqlDatabase).Count
    }}
```

If you are unable to install the SqlServer module you can do it with the [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

```
#load the assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO")
#read server names from a file
$servers = get-content "C:\Some\Path\servers.txt"
#use calculated properties
$servers | select-object `
    @{Name='ServerName';Expression={$_}},
    @{Name='DatabaseCount';Expression={
        (New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server $_).Databases.Count
    }}
```

Output:

```
ServerName          DatabaseCount
----------          -------------
ServerOne                      12
ServerTwo                      22
ServerThree                     6
```

Note that there is no error checking and I am assuming that you are running in a context that has rights to the server and DB engine.

Comment: Hi Stephen, This is really very helpful for me, just one more question " What would be the format for servers in servers.txt file? "

Comment: Just one servername per line

Comment: Many Thanks Stephen :)

Comment: Hi Stephen, I tried do it with the SMO query but in output only server names are showing database counts only heading shows and nothing. Can you suggest me if any change is required in script.

Comment: If count is returning nothing you will need to investigate why `(New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server $_).Databases` is not returning any values. There could be a variety of reasons from insufficient permissions to missing components or misconfiguration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I found the reason, some servers were decommissioned hence not showing results, can we get database name, database creation date also along with database count.?

Comment: You can but, that's getting a bit more complicated than just a count. Instead of counting them you can send them to a foreach loop and then extract the properties you want. I would recommend trying to write something and opening it as a different question as that would change the scope of this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Functions with Timer schedule to automate what you want.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer
And you can use stored procedures with azure functions.

Comment: this is not, what I am looking for